# What's the definition of equational theory? Why is λ logic free?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

A book says that "λ is logic free: it is an equational theory." But I don't understand the "logic free" and "equational theory". Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the claim. It is not at all obvious how to model variable binding in a purely equational way...

Comment: I support Zhen Lin's doubts: See Henk Barendregt & Wil Dekkers & Richard Statman, *Lambda Calculus with Types* (2013), page 6 : "**Definition**. On  $\Lambda$ [the set of $\lambda$-terms] the following *equational theory* $\lambda \beta \eta$  is defined by the usual equality axiom and rules ---", but (page 5) : "**Definition**. Let $M \in \Lambda$. The set of free variables of $M$, notation $FV(M)$, is defined as follows : [...] for $M := \lambda x P , FV(P) − \{ x \}$". Thus $\lambda$ **is** a *varible-binding* operator.

Comment: @Zhen Lin I have just started to learn this knowledge. Could you recommend some materials(book, paper or link) talking about equational theory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199215626) (2007), Ch.5 : **Quantifier-free logic**, page 101-on.

It is used a first-order language **without** quantifiers and it is studied a *natural deduction* calculus for *quantifier-free* formulas :

> Atomic formulas of the form $(s = t)$ are called *equations*, and the symbol ‘$=$’ is known as equality or identity.
>
> The natural deduction rules for qf formulas are exactly the same as for $LP$ [*propositional logic*], except that we also have introduction and elimination rules ($=$I), ($=$E) for equality.

Thus, basically, we can construct derivations "made of" equations.

*Added*

See Henk Barendregt, [The Lambda Calculus. Its Syntax and Semantics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184890066X) (2nd revised ed - 1985), page 6 :

> The theory $\lambda$ [of *pure lambda calculus*] has as terms the set $\Lambda$ ($\lambda$-*terms*) built up from variables using application and abstraction. The statements of $\lambda$ are equations between $\lambda$-terms [...].

See page 23 :

> Note that $\lambda$ is *logic free* [emphasis added]: it is an equational theory. Connectives and quantifiers will be used in the informal metalanguage discussing about $\lambda$.

From these quotations, the intent of the author is clear. The mathematical theory of *pure lambda calculus* is based on a syntax of *terms*, where the set $\Lambda$ of it is built up form *variables* ($v_0, v_1, ...$), the parentheses and the *abstractor* $\lambda$ [see Def.2.1.1, page 22], and the formulas of the calculus are equations between terms of the form $M=N$ where $M,N \in \Lambda$ [see Def.2.1.4, page 23].

The formulas have *no* logical *connectives* : $\lnot$, $\land$, $\rightarrow$, nor the "usual" quantifiers : $\forall$, $\exists$; in this sense it is "logic free".

Expressions like :

> $M = N \implies N = M$

or :

> $\forall M \, (\lambda x.x) M = M$

with connectives and quantifiers, are **not** formulas of the language, but statements in the meta-language describing the $\lambda$ calculus.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't figure out how could the quantifier-free logic help me understand the concepts I ask.

Comment: @Lily - this an "example" of "equational" theory. According to Barendregt' books, $\lambda$ calculus is an *equational theory*. What is not clear from your citation is the meaning of "logic free" ; does it mean : quantifier free ? Perhaps, the info about the book you are using may help ...

Comment: The book I'm using is H.P. Barendregt's _The Lambda Calculus: Its Syntax and Semantics_. This claim is on the page 23 "Note that λ is logic free: It is an equational theory". There are nothing talking the meaning of "logic free".

Comment: I had the same question and was directed here. Great answer!

Comment: @ZiqiFan - you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a broad class of "formal systems": each comes with a set of symbols, a set of statements or well-formed formulas, axioms and rules how to define new formulas from axioms. The derivable formulas in a given formal system called "the theory of the system".

Then "propositional logic" or "first order logic" refer to a subclass of formal systems, their set of symbols contain operators that can be called "logical", and either the axioms or the rules will contain "logical" reasoning; we are talking about conjunction, disjunction, implication, logical equivalence, negation, forall, exists (not necessarily all of them).

(Note that there are often several equivalent ways to get reasoning: axiomatic ("Hilbert style"), where there are "logical" axioms and the only inference rule is Modus Ponens, or in Natural Deduction or Sequent Calculus where we get reasoning through the inference rules and the only axioms are the "non-logical" ones)

The lambda-calculus is a formal system where the only well-formed formulas are equations. Therefore, the rules serve to derive new equations from existing ones, the theory is "equational".

In order to use lambda calculus for logical reasoning, one can add "logical" connectors in the form of constants, with axioms (equations) giving these connectors their expected meaning. See the article by Farmer "The seven virtues of simple type theory" or the book by Andrews "An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory"